# Require some inputs to make piece of code better with Java-8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have small piece of code (POJO) with java-8. My question is can I do something better with using java-8? I have mentioned some comments in class.

Assume that I have `Person`, `Standard` and `Subject` pojos and also do not worry about `equals` and `hashCode` methods, I just want inputs with respect to `Java-8`.

```
package com.java8.learn.domain;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * @author Vishal.Zanzrukia
 *
 */
public class Teacher extends Person {

    private Map<Standard, Set<Subject>> standardWiseSubjects;

    public Map<Standard, Set<Subject>> getStandardWiseSubjects() {
        return standardWiseSubjects;
    }

    public void addStandardWiseSubject(Subject subject, Standard standard) {
        if (this.standardWiseSubjects == null) {
            this.standardWiseSubjects = new HashMap<>();
        }
        if (this.standardWiseSubjects.containsKey(standard)) {
            this.standardWiseSubjects.get(standard).add(subject);
        } else {
            Set<Subject> subjects = new HashSet<>();
            subjects.add(subject);
            this.standardWiseSubjects.put(standard, subjects);
        }
    }

    // I need some inputs over here.
    public Map<Subject, Set<Standard>> getSubjectWiseStandards() {

        if (this.standardWiseSubjects == null) {
            return null;
        }

        Map<Subject, Set<Standard>> output = new HashMap<>();

        this.standardWiseSubjects.values().parallelStream().flatMap(set -> set.stream()).forEach(subject -> {
            Set<Standard> standards = new HashSet<>();
            this.standardWiseSubjects.forEach((standard, subjects) -> {
                // TODO can I convert this if condition into predicate?
                if (subjects.contains(subject)) {
                    standards.add(standard);
                }
            });
            output.put(subject, standards);
        });

        return output;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `addStandardWiseSubject` method can be simplified using the `computeIfAbsent` method:

```
public void addStandardWiseSubject(Subject subject, Standard standard) {
    if (this.standardWiseSubjects == null) {
        this.standardWiseSubjects = new HashMap<>();
    }
    this.standardWiseSubjects.computeIfAbsent(standard,
            s -> new HashSet<>()).add(subject);
}
```

The `getSubjectWiseStandards()` is trickier: you need to invert the map. It can be done producing the intermediate pairs of all subjects and corresponding standards (I used the `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry` class to represent such pair):

```
public Map<Subject, Set<Standard>> getSubjectWiseStandards() {
    if (this.standardWiseSubjects == null) {
        return null;
    }

    return this.standardWiseSubjects.entrySet().parallelStream()
        .<Map.Entry<Subject, Standard>> flatMap(
                e -> e.getValue().stream()
                    .map(st -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(st, e.getKey())))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.getKey(), 
                 Collectors.mapping(e -> e.getValue(), 
                 Collectors.toSet())));
}
```

This may look simpler using the `EntryStream` class of my [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) library:

```
public Map<Subject, Set<Standard>> getSubjectWiseStandards() {
    if (this.standardWiseSubjects == null) {
        return null;
    }

    return EntryStream.of(this.standardWiseSubjects).parallel()
            .invert().flatMapKeys(Set::stream).groupingTo(HashSet::new);
}
```

Please note that `forEach` with parallel stream should be used with extreme care as it can be executed for different elements in parallel. Your solution may work incorrectly as you modify the `HashMap` (which is not thread-safe) from this `forEach` operation.

Comment: thank you so much for this answer, I have one small query regarding `<Map.Entry<Subject, Standard>>` which you have mentioned just before using the `flatMap`. How it works before calling method? and what it role of it at that place? is it compulsory or optional to declare that?

Comment: @VishalZanzrukia, it's just an explicit generic parameter for `flatMap` method (its resulting type). Usually such parameters can be inferred automatically, but here the expression is quite long and complex so compiler may not be able to infer it.

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible like below

```
Map<Standard, Set<Subject>> map = new HashMap<Standard, Set<Subject>>();
Map<Subject, Set<Standard>> reverseMap = new HashMap<Subject, Set<Standard>>();
HashSet<Subject> std1Subjects = new HashSet<Subject>();
std1Subjects.add(new Subject("English"));
std1Subjects.add(new Subject("Maths"));
std1Subjects.add(new Subject("Science"));

HashSet<Subject> std2Subjects = new HashSet<Subject>();
std2Subjects.add(new Subject("Hindi"));
std2Subjects.add(new Subject("Gujarati"));
std2Subjects.add(new Subject("Maths"));

HashSet<Subject> std3Subjects = new HashSet<Subject>();
std3Subjects.add(new Subject("Sanskrit"));
std3Subjects.add(new Subject("Science"));
std3Subjects.add(new Subject("Maths"));

map.put(new Standard("1"), std1Subjects);
map.put(new Standard("2"), std2Subjects);
map.put(new Standard("3"), std3Subjects);

//1.
map.keySet().forEach((std) -> map.get(std).forEach((sub)->{
    if(reverseMap.containsKey(sub)){
        reverseMap.get(sub).add(std);
    }else{
        HashSet<Standard> standardSet = new HashSet<Standard>();
        standardSet.add(std);
        reverseMap.put(sub, standardSet);
    }
}));

reverseMap
        .forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println("k-" + k + " , v-" + v));
```

And also like below

```
map.keySet().forEach((std) -> map.get(std).forEach((sub)->{
            reverseMap.computeIfAbsent(sub,standard-> new HashSet<>()).add(std);
            reverseMap.computeIfPresent(sub, (subject,stdSet) -> reverseMap.get(subject)).add(std);
        }));
```